# How to attach string to best value out of loop?

Tags: java, loops

I have an assignment for college to do and I was wondering if anyone could help me. Task isn't very complicated but I'm struggling with loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
    //S = Start
    //F = Finish
    //R = Race ( Final )
   byte i = 0;
   int sHours =  0,     sMinutes =  0, sSeconds = 0;
   int fHours =  0,     fMinutes =  0, fSeconds = 0;
   int sTime =   0,     fTime =     0,    rTime = 0 ; 
   int highest = 0;
   int rHours =  0,     rMinutes =  0, rSeconds = 0; 
   String name = null,  bestRunner = null;
   char gender = 0; 

    for(i = 1; i<=3; i++)
        {

        System.out.println("Please enter " + i + "runner's name");  
        name = sc.next();

        System.out.println("Please enter" + name + " runner's gender (M / F)");  
        gender = sc.next().charAt(0);

              System.out.println("Enter " + i + "'st runner's STARTING time(Seperated by space) : "); 
              sHours   = sc.nextInt(); 
              sMinutes = sc.nextInt(); 
              sSeconds = sc.nextInt(); 

              System.out.println("Enter " + i + "'st runner's FINISHING time hours: "); 
              fHours   = sc.nextInt(); 
              fMinutes = sc.nextInt(); 
              fSeconds = sc.nextInt(); 

              //Converting to seconds
              sTime = ((sHours*3600)+(sMinutes*60)+sSeconds); 
              fTime = ((fHours*3600)+(fMinutes*60)+fSeconds); 
              rTime = ((fTime - sTime)); 
              //Best time recording to loop
              if (i == 1 || rTime < highest){ 
                  highest = rTime;  
                  bestRunner = name;  
              } 
        }



        System.out.println("Name\t\tGender\t\tStart Time    \tFinish time\t\tRACE TIME"); 
        System.out.println(name + gender + rTime);

       sc.close();
}
```

}

Okay so my problem is with:

```
if (i == 1 || rTime < highest){ 
    highest = rTime;  
    bestRunner = name;  
}
```

I want to record best time of the runners I inputed and in the output line I want to show best time and the runners name. (I will deal with gender issue later)
Problem is that it's **always the last loop input is recorded, not the lowest one.**

This question might be asked before but I still couldn't figure out whats the issue.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to check if `rTime > highest`?

Comment: i think the variable names are off @clcto.. Wouldn't the bestRunner have the lowest time? heh

Comment: @austinwernli fair enough

Comment: Okay, so I have to override `highest` to last runners time?

Comment: ah ok, dunno how I missed such a simple logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've saved the name you care about in `bestRunner`, but you print out `name` instead. Same for `highest` and `rTime`

```
System.out.println(name + gender + rTime);
```

Should be:

```
System.out.println(bestRunner + gender + highest);
```

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to change it. It's so confusing!

Comment: Okay, it seems to work. But why it didn't worked? Shouldn't it override the `name` to `bestrunner`?

Comment: And what will happen if 2 times will be exactly the same? Is it going to output the value which was entered first or second?

Comment: @RoccoMikal `bestRunner = name;` is a one way operation, it assigns `name` to `bestRunner` but does not tie them together in anyway.

Comment: Look at your condition: `rTime < highest`. Can you tell me?

Comment: What do you mean? rTime `IS LOWER` than last time?

Comment: Well lower than the previous lowest. So it only assigns the later values if it is lower, not if they are equal. `rTime <= highest` will assign the later values if it is lower or equal. So in your code, the first will be outputted.

Comment: Okay, I understand. You explained everything very simple! I will do the same thing with gender now!